# Python new_station-= 1 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

```py
print ("                Welcome to Kelana Jaya LRT ticketing system            ")
print ("")
def stations():
    print ("List of Stations")
    list_station = ["Taman Bahagia","Taman Paramount","Asia Jaya","Taman Jaya","Universiti","Kerinchi","Abdullah Hukum","Bangsar","KL Sentral","Pasar Seni","Masjid Jamek","Dang Wangi","Kampung Baru","KLCC","Ampang Park","Setiawangsa","Terminal Putra"]
    num = 0
    station = 1
    while num < 17:
        print (station,"." ,list_station[num])
        num += 1
        station +=1
    print ("")
    new_station = input("Please select station you willing to go by inserting the relevant number : ")
    print ("")
    new_station-= 1

    print ("You inserted number " ,new_station + 1, ",Station" ,list_station[new_station],".")
    return new_station
new_station = stations()
num_tickets=input("How many tickets you willing to purchase : ")
```

Comment: new_station-= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string (in Python 3). You will have to convert it to an `int` if you want it to be an `int`:

```
new_station = int(input("Please select station you willing to go by inserting the relevant number : "))
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\nadar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\k.py", line 15, in stations
    new_station-= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'